# blender UI locking up

Tags: performance

I am using blender 2.93.107.0 to model a chess set and board.  I added a panel to use as a board and applied materials.  Now, it locks up almost immediately after opening the blend file.  I have noticed that:

1. it doesn't lock up until I try to "do something".  Like if I rotate an object it will start to rotate it but then freeze.
2. it seems the issue could be with the panel and, perhaps more specifically, the material as it wasn't doing it before.

Why this is happening or how I can troubleshoot?

I deleted the plane and created a new one without a material.  It hasn't crashed yet.

[Blend file](https://pasteall.org/blend/ef090be2e0674cb5b8319befcbbc1d92)

Comment: 2.93 LTS is on version 7 now (2.93.7) so it might be worth updating before going any further, but you can upload your file here: https://pasteall.org/blend/ . Don't forget to edit your question and add the link to the file.

Comment: I was actually using version 3 but when it had this error I downloaded 2.93 just to see if it would happen there as well.  So, yes, it is happening in both environments.

Comment: Your downloaded file is fine here both in 2.93 and 3.0 although it doesn't have the checkerboard material for the board of course so I've no idea what caused that.